# Get free space of "C:" drive using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file which gives me free space left in C drive.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293780/free-space-in-a-cmd-shell

Answer (score 4):

The following script will give you free bytes on the drive:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('dir c:\') do (
    set bytesfree=%%a
)
set bytesfree=%bytesfree:,=%
echo %bytesfree%
endlocal && set bytesfree=%bytesfree%
```

Note that this depends on the output of your `dir` command, which needs the last line containing the free space of the format `24 Dir(s) 34,071,691,264 bytes free`. Specifically:

- it must be the last line (or you can modify the `for` loop to detect the line explicitly rather than relying on setting `bytesfree` for every line).
- the free space must be the third "word" (or you can change the `tokens=` bit to get a different word).
- thousands separators are the `,` character (or you can change the substitution from comma to something else).

It doesn't pollute your environment namespace, setting only the `bytesfree` variable on exit. If your `dir` output is different (eg, different locale or language settings), you will need to adjust the script.

Comment: I had to use the output from this script and build an `if` expression to determine if I had to delete old files off a drive. I used:
`ECHO %bytesfree%>x&FOR %%? IN (x) DO SET /A strlen=%%~z? - 2&del x *newline* IF %strlen% LEQ 13 [...]`