# Multiplication of numbers with more than 64 bits in batch

Tags: batch-file, encryption

I'm creating an encryption program, and the way it works is, every character is replaced with a specified number, then added to the full string. Then the option will be given to encrypt it with a password. The password is then also translated using a set of given numbers. The two strings will then be multiplied. As you can imagine, an entire message could very easily result in more than 64 bits of number. I need a way to get the answer and then put that number into a text file, preferably without having to do anything else manually. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use PowerShell rather than `cmd.exe`.

Comment: For once, I agree with Bill. Math involving numbers larger than 2^32 (or non-integers) should be done by PowerShell.

Comment: In pure batch scripting you have to work around the 32-bit limitation (see [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33357948)); you can call PowerShell from a batch file however like in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13109266)...

Comment: I'm trying to get more than 64 bits of information, though. PowerShell still gives me the answer in scientific notation like VBScript and CMD. I'd like to think that there's a program out there that breaks the numbers down and multiplies each number individually like they teach you in school, but I'm beginning to think that just isn't even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this magical batch file at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/multiply_3rdparty_bat.txt.

The standard output of the file should be the answer to any multiplication problem, which you can retrieve with a *for* command like so:

```
for /f %%A in ('multiply.cmd !key! !message!') do set ciphertext=%%A
```

However, at numbers this size, it is not safe to do normal arithmetic operations. It should be treated as a string.

Comment: Thank you so much! This appears to work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "anum=333333333333333334"
SET "bnum=3"
CALL :longmult cnum anum bnum
ECHO %anum% * %bnum%=%cnum%
GOTO :EOF

:longmult
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "$=!%2!"
SET "$0=0"
FOR /l %%x IN (1,1,9) DO CALL :longadd $%%x $!$0! $&SET "$0=%%x"
SET "$0=0"
SET "$="
SET "$$=!%3!"
SET "$$$="
:mloop
CALL :longaddvr $ !$%$$:~-1%!%$$$% $
SET "$$$=%$$$%0"
SET "$$=%$$:~0,-1%
IF DEFINED $$ GOTO mloop
endlocal&SET "%1=%$%"
GOTO :eof

:: Longadd reference to reference
:longadd
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "p3=!%3!"
SET "p2=!%2!"
:: Have values to be added in P2,P3
:longacomm
SET "$="
SET /a $carry=0
:addloop
IF DEFINED p2 IF DEFINED p3 (
 SET /a $carry=$carry+%p2:~-1%+%p3:~-1%
 SET "p2=%p2:~0,-1%"
 SET "p3=%p3:~0,-1%"
 SET "$=!$carry:~-1!%$%"
 SET /a $carry/=10
 GOTO addloop
)
IF %$carry%==1 (
 IF NOT DEFINED p2 SET /a p2=0
 IF NOT DEFINED p3 SET /a p3=0
 GOTO addloop
)
SET "$=%p2%%p3%%$%"
endlocal&SET "%1=%$%"
GOTO :eof

:: Longadd value to reference
:longaddvr
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "p3=!%3!"
SET "p2=%~2"
GOTO longacomm
```

Here's a routine to multiply the values of two variables giving a third.

How it works I'll leave as an exercise for those interested.