# How to write in the same line like a typewriter?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I wrote this hybrid **[Batch/Vbscript]** ([inspired by this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301198/get-size-of-a-directory-in-mb-using-batch-file?answertab=active#tab-top))

in order to simulate something like a typewriter !

But, i can't figure out how we can write in same line like a typewriter ?

```
@echo off
Set Message=Hi ! StackOverFlow !
@cScript.EXE //noLogo "%~f0?.WSF" "%Message%" //job:info %~nx0%*
pause
<job id="info">
<script language="VBScript">
strText=wscript.arguments(0)
intTextLen = Len(strText)
intPause = 100
For x = 1 to intTextLen
    strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1)
    wscript.echo strTempText
    WScript.Sleep intPause
    If intPause <= 500 Then
        intPause = intPause + 100
    Else
        intPause = 100
    End If
Next
</script>
</job>
```

Comment: I find it surprising that with the answers you have given on [so] you will need to ask this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must write to the [StdOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c61dx86d%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) stream.

```
str = "hello world!"
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    WScript.StdOut.Write Mid(str, i, 1)
    WScript.Sleep 50
Next
```