# Take required space from available space and store in a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Ok,I have this code:

```
echo [%time%] Beginning install
echo [%time%] Checking hard drive C:\
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in (`"wmic logicaldisk  where name='C:' get  FreeSpace /format:value"`) do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%%#") do @set "%%a"
)
echo [%time%] Available space: %freespace% Bytes
echo [%time%] Required space: 34 Megabytes
@set requiredspace=34
@set /a "available_required=%freespace%-%requiredspace%"
echo [%time%] %available_required%
pause
```

It finds the available storage on a hard drive and takes away the required to find out if there is enough storage to complete the install, unfortunately, Windows CMD doesn't like numbers higher than 32 bit so I need to cut it down to megabytes, the maths cant be done on the stored variable so It has to be found directly from the command.
For example, (Obviously not working though)

```
"wmic logicaldisk  where name='C:' get  FreeSpace /format:value /division:megabytes"
```

Thanks

Comment: Why didn't you just include this in your previous question?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36318398) you can find a pure [tag:batch-file] solution for performing a division (by 1024*1024) of a number exceeding the signed 32-bit integer range...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of utilising WMIC, you could leverage powershell for your freespace calculation directly into MegaBytes:

```bat
@Echo Off

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Powershell "gWMI Win32_LogicalDisk"^
 "-F ""DeviceID='C:'""""|%%{[Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1MB,0)}"'
) Do Set "FDS=%%A"
Echo=Freespace on C: is %FDS%MB

Timeout -1
```

If you were looking for GB to two decimal places then a quick edit of the above could achieve that too:

```bat
@Echo Off

For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Powershell "gWMI Win32_LogicalDisk"^
 "-F ""DeviceID='C:'""""|%%{[Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}"'
) Do Set "FDS=%%A"
Echo=Freespace on C: is %FDS%GB

Timeout -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick-and-dirty:

```
set "freespace=%freespace:~0,-6%"
echo [%time%] Available space: %freespace% MBytes
```

Divides freespace by 1,000,000 rather than 1024^2

Answer (score 0):

You can pad the values and compare them as strings

```dos
set "rSpace=00000000000035651584"
set "fSpace=00000000000000000000%freeSpace%"
if "%rSpace:~-20%" gtr "%fSpace:~-20%" (
    echo [%time%] Not enough space available
) else (
    echo [%time%] Enough Space available
)
```