# Getting the Folder size for only subfolders, whist ignoring any other content?

Tags: vbscript

I’ve created the script below, which manages and maintains allocated storage within a RootFolder, into which are stored daily backups each within its sown individual folder, and should the RootFolder content exceed a preset limit, then the oldest backup folder is then deleted.

So far so good . . . the problem I have is that largeish files may also be added to the RootFolder [strHomeFolder] and as such are also included in the total accumulated 'size'.  As a consequence the backup folders may be prematurely deleted, and in the worst case scenario all may be deleted altogether, which unfortunately may somewhat defeat the purpose of having backups !

I am therefore seeking advice in makeing the objFSO.GetFolder check only the contents of all of the backup Folders located within the RootFolder whilst ignoring any of the files at that level.

```
strOldestFolder = ""
dtmOldestDate = Now

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\HDBackups")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strHomeFolder)

intFolderSize = Int((objFolder.Size / 1024) / 1024)

If intFolderSize >= 50 Then ' change as appropriate value in MBytes
    Set objSubFolders = objFolder.SubFolders
    For Each objFolder in objSubFolders
        strFolder = objFolder.Path
        dtmFolderDate = objFolder.DateCreated
        If dtmFolderDate < dtmOldestDate Then
            dtmOldestDate = dtmFolderDate
            strOldestFolder = strFolder
        End If
    Next
    objFSO.DeleteFolder(strOldestFolder)
End If
```

Comment: Iterate over the subfolders (like you already do in the bottom half of your code) and sum up the values of their `Size` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop through the Root folder's `SubFolders` and sum up `intFolderSize`:

```
strOldestFolder = ""
dtmOldestDate = Now

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%\HDBackups")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strHomeFolder)

Dim objSubFolder
intFolderSize = 0
For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    intFolderSize = intFolderSize + objSubFolder.Size
Next

intFolderSize = Int((intFolderSize / 1024) / 1024)

If intFolderSize >= 50 Then ' change as appropriate value in MBytes
    Set objSubFolders = objFolder.SubFolders
    For Each objFolder In objSubFolders
        strFolder = objFolder.Path
        dtmFolderDate = objFolder.DateCreated
        If dtmFolderDate < dtmOldestDate Then
            dtmOldestDate = dtmFolderDate
            strOldestFolder = strFolder
        End If
    Next
    objFSO.DeleteFolder (strOldestFolder)
End If
```

Comment: Just the job, excellent, have also added it to my ‘file only’ script, so now I can independently manage both . . . once again many thanks