# get size of a directory in mb using batch file?

Tags: batch-file

how can you write the return value of "Call :GetSize %Folder%" into a variable? from this link.[Get size of a directory in 'MB' using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301198/get-size-of-a-directory-in-mb-using-batch-file/48182979#48182979)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
Set Folder="c:\users\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('CScript.EXE //noLogo "%~f0?.WSF" %Folder%  //job:info %~nx0%*') do set "out=%%a"
echo(%out%
pause
@exit /b 0
<job id="info">
(so on and so on... rest of the code)
```

For information about FOR command, check [this link](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), or type `for /?` on your CMD.