# Putting IF condition in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I want to check if space in C: drive is more than 60 GB then next step should be done and if space is less it should display a message?

For checking the disk space i can use "fsutil volume diskfree c:" but i dont know how to use it inside the above condition.

Comment: describe your environment,.. windows linux  ??

Comment: if linux tell about your default shell

Comment: Is it free space or total space that you want to check?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are fine with treating 1 GB as 10<sup>9</sup> bytes, not as 2<sup>30</sup> bytes, you could simply

1) pipe the results of `FSUTIL` to the `FIND` utility to filter out irrelevant rows,

2) use the modified command line in a `FOR /F` loop to store the output into a variable,

3) cut off the last 9 characters from the variable's value and compare the rest to the required quantity.

And here's my attempt at putting the above steps together:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET required=60
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%A IN ('fsutil volume diskfree c: ^| find "# of bytes"') DO SET "space=%%A"
IF %space:~0,-9% LSS %required% ECHO Space is less than %required% GB!
```

The above script processes the total space. If you want to check the free space, change `"# of bytes"` to `"# of free"`.

Answer (score 1):

Basic `IF` reading : http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true

similar blog post here : 
http://fei-automation.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-monitor-free-space-of-group-of.html

similar SO : [Free space in a CMD shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293780/free-space-in-a-cmd-shell)