# How to get disk space of windows machine with R?

Tags: r, windows, cmd

How can I get the total disk space / free disk space of my windows computer ?

If there is no R function, maybe there is a windows command that I could use within the R `system` function but I wasn't able to find that command.

Comment: For a `system` solution, take a look at [Free space in a CMD shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293780/free-space-in-a-cmd-shell) (the `dir` command mentioned there should work).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though I find it *really* difficult to believe that a Google search for `windows cmd disk space` came up empty for you, this should provide the information you need w/o the need for admin privileges:

```
disks <- system("wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption", inter=TRUE)

disks <- read.fwf(textConnection(disks[1:(length(disks)-1)]), 
         widths=c(9, 13, 13), strip.white=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

colnames(disks) <- disks[1,]
disks <- disks[-1,]
rownames(disks) <- NULL

disks

##   Caption   FreeSpace        Size
## 1      A:                        
## 2      C: 52617023488 63898120192
## 3      D:
```

Just thought I'd also add that this answer comes from someone who is primarily an OS X/Linux user.

Comment: I didn't use the right keywords I guess... I would have prefered find the answer directly with a google search than taking the time to write a question. Anyway thanks, this is exactly what I need ! And indeed it works w/o admin privileges.

Comment: Btw why do you set a length of 12 for the 3rd column ? The values of the column "Size" will always be at least the same length as "FreeSpace" no ?

Comment: there's a 2 space buffer between them. the 12 avoids any chance of taking the inane MS-DOS `\r`'s along for the ride.

Comment: OK, but it seems to drop the last number of the "Size" value for disk space >~ 93Gb (1e11 bytes). For example : `read.fwf(textConnection("C:       364533350400  481852125184  \r"), 
         widths = c(9, 13, 12), strip.white = TRUE)` Results in : `1 C: 364533350400 48185212518`. And i'm not experiencing troubles using 13+ widths. EDIT : SO drops duplicated spaces in string.. :/